# Scorm 2004 has really failed?

Tags: scorm2004

For a project in e-learning courses I want to implement the standard scorm 2004 in my LMS (Learning management system), for that I did a little research about the standard. Among the results that I found, many articles talk about the "failure" of scorm 2004. The standard seems to me very little implemented in the existing LMS. This article [Aticle scorm 2004](https://www.efrontlearning.com/blog/2013/04/why-scorm-2004-failed-what-that-means-for-tin-can.html), for example, indicates the disadvantages of the standard and compares it with the other standards ans we can see a very big difference. I also found on Internent that Moodle has abandoned the implementation of SCORM 2004 on its LMS. In addition, when we look at the documentation of the scorm 2004 (the books CAM, RTE and SN) we soon realize the completeness of the standard.

Do you think the standard has really failed?

Comment: you can read the three books to correctly understand this standard. I think the decision to implement depends on the size of your project. I advise you to check if there are LMS that have implemented scorm 2004. it will allow you to have a more precise idea.

Comment: thank you @Mouaici_Med , I search to have gloabl idea before starting the implementation of scorm 2004. because I think that can take a lot of time, and if I spent a lot of time and realize in the end that the scorm 2004 has really failed, It will be very hard for me!! Do you have some example of LMS that has implemented this standard ?

Comment: yes I see, I don't know if there are some LMS that implements this standard, but you can chek the officiel web site of scorm 2004 in [link](http://scorm.com/)

Comment: thank you very much @Mouaici_Med

Comment: SCORM 2004 did not fail, the failure was that there was a lack of widespread *adoption* of SCORM 2004. It's incredibly complex to implement for both LMS vendors and course developers, so many folks simply skipped it, or only implemented the parts they liked. FYI this question is not really appropriate for StackOverflow since it is not a programming question. You may want to try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or Quora

Comment: This was a DOD e-learning API white paper standard.  You would have to ask them hah.  But for the rest of the adopters I imagine you would have to take in feedback by and from providers, creators, developers and students.  I agree with @pipwerks this is not an appropriate place for this.